# Remove all files except for a few, from a folder in Unix

Tags: unix, rm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete all files in a directory except some?](https://superuser.com/questions/529854/how-to-delete-all-files-in-a-directory-except-some)

I often face this problem. I have a set of files in a folder and would like to delete all of them except a few.

For example: I have files named according to the date of creation (like 11-1-11.tar, 10-1-11.tar and so on). Now I would like to delete files like 10-1-11, 9-1-11 and so on but not some other files. Basically I would like to enforce what all should be deleted and what should be retained. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

If this is BASH, you could consider using extended globbing. To enable:

`shopt -s extglob`

(Put that in your `.bashrc` if you want, or just turn it on when you need it.)

And then, e.g., to delete all the files *except* filename1 and filename2

`rm !(filename1|filename2)`

You can also use wildcards like * in there too.

Or you could delete all those matching a pattern:

`rm +([0-9])-+([0-9])-+([0-9]).tar`

would delete all #-#-#.tar files (where the numbers have 1 or more digits).

It's unclear whether this would meet your needs or not. More details [here](http://aplawrence.com/Words2005/2005_05_25.html).

Answer (score 2):

If the filename corresponds with the creation date of the file, it may just be easier to delete files older than a certain day.

This is easily achieved with the find command:

```
find /home/john/files -type f -mtime +30 -delete
```

this would delete files under `/home/john/files` which have a modification date longer than 30 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

you may also be able to do what you want with tmpwatch

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_tmpwatch.htm

```
tmpwatch -m 24 /path/to/dir
```

will delete all files in the dir older than one day since last used (-m).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use several UNIX command in one pipe and it will solve your problem.
One of possible solution is using `find | grep | xargs rm -rf`.
For example:

`$ find /path/to/directory/tree -type f | grep -v -E -f /path/to/exclude/file | xargs rm -rf`

For excluding some files just put their names into file `/path/to/exclude/file`. For example:

```
very_useful_file.tar.gz
very_important_file.jpg
```

For preventing incorrect wiping of important files I suggest make backup copy of all files. 
It's also useful using xargs with `-p` option, which `...Prompt the user about whether to run each command line and read a line from the terminal.`

It's possible to use `find` tool without grep/xargs. It will be something like that:
`find /path/to/tree -type f ! -name "exlude_pattern"`

Before using these commands read manual pages carefully for `find/grep/xargs`! They can be very dangerous:).

Comment: You might also want to carefully consider whether you want to use `-r` (recursive) (and perhaps `-f` (force)) when you're feeding filenames to `xargs` for `rm`.