# Remove files which have a certain syntax

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, regex, rm

I have a couple of files which follow this syntax:

- *_yyyy-mm-dd_hhhmmm.*

Example:

- *_2010-01-01_00h10m.*
- *_2010-01-01_01h10m.*
- *_2010-01-01_02h10m.*
- *_2010-01-01_03h10m.*
- ...
- *_2010-01-01_23h10m.*
- *_2010-02-01_00h10m.*
- *_2010-02-01_01h10m.*
- *_2010-02-01_02h10m.*
- ...
- *_2010-02-01_23h10m.*
- ...
- *_2010-12-01_23h10m.*

I would like to keep only this files

- *_2010-01-01_00h10m.*
- *_2010-02-01_00h10m.*
- *_2010-03-01_00h10m.*
- ...
- *_2010-12-01_00h10m.*

and delete the others. or maybe move them to a subdirectory to be safe...

**Does someone has a smart on-liner for this challenge?**

Thanks, Udo

Comment: similar http://superuser.com/questions/231718/remove-all-files-except-for-a-few-from-a-folder-in-unix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(*_2010-??-01_00h10m.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

very naive way

```
mkdir keep_these
mkdir remove_these
mv *_00h10m* keep_these
mv *.* remove_these
```

or a oneliner

```
ls * | grep -v "_00h10m" | while read a; do mv $a /tmp; done
```

Comment: naive indeed :) -> but good -> do you also have a solution without the need of subdirs?

Comment: @udo - Yes just replace `mv $a /tmp` with `\rm $a´ in the last example