# How to delete all files in a directory except some?

Tags: linux, bash, rm

I need to delete all files in a directory, but exclude some of them. For example, in a directory with the files `a b c ... z`, I need to delete all except for `u` and `p`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: The answers below are a lot better, but you could just make the files to save read-only, delete all, and then change them back to their original permissions (as long as you don't use rm -f).  You'd have to know what permissions to restore and you'd have to know that nothing needed write access to them during the process.  This is why the other answers are better.

Comment: If you also want to delete hidden files run `shopt -s dotglob` before running `rm (...)`.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

What I do in those cases is to type

```
rm *
```

Then I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>*</kbd> to *expand* `*` into all visible file names.

Then I can just remove the two files I like to keep from the list and finally execute the command line.

Comment: I guess this works only as long as the list of files which `*` expands too isn't getting too long. :-}

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: Indeed. If it's too long a different approach will be required. Luckily we now have a list of great options :)

Comment: Esc followed by * will also expand the "*".

Comment: This only works with `rm`; was looking for `mv`, `cp`, `chmod` etc.. :(

Comment: @SantoshKumar: That doesn't make sense to me. The expansion will always work, it doesn't depend on what command you want to use afterwards.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Sorry, the combination is little bit confusing. I think you should write like `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `x` + `*`

Comment: @SantoshKumar: But that's not the combination.

Comment: Works in practice but can't be scripted. I think the find solution is the best.

Comment: @Oliver Salzburg, the combination is not working on my Korn shell , what I might be doing wrong could you please advise? solution from slowpoision , esc followed by * worked though. Thanks

Answer (score 145):

To `rm` all but `u,p` in bash just type:

```
rm !(u|p)
```

This requires the following option to be set:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

See more: [glob - Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)

Comment: you must have 'extglobbing' active: shopt -s extglob

Comment: You need to `shopt -s extglob`, @Ashot. Also, it's just files, not directories, which is why I've removed the `-rf` options in your command.

Comment: If you need to exclude one file **of a selection** of files, try this: `rm !(index).html`. This will delete all files ending in ".html" with the exception of "index.html".

Comment: just erased all of my files. thanks

Answer (score 84):

You can use `find`

```
find . ! -name u ! -name p -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete
```

- `!` negates the next expression
- `-name` specifies a filename
- `-maxdepth 1` will make find process the specified directory only (`find` by default traverses directories)
- `-type f` will process only files (and not for example directories)
- `-delete` will delete the files

You can then tune the conditions looking at the [man page of find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)

**Update**

- Keep in mind that the order of the elements of the expressions is significant (see the documentation)
- Test your command first by using `-print` instead of `-delete`

  ```
  find . ! -name u ! -name p -maxdepth 1 -type f -print
  ```

Comment: order of predicates is critical here. If one put `-delete` just after `.` it will be disaster (will delete all files in CWD)

Comment: This could be written more compactly as `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '[^up]' -delete`

Comment: @kojiro yes but only for files that are just one letter. With more complex names the regex could be a mess.

Comment: `find` is my best friend, especially when there are too many files to glob

Comment: +1 for the explanation of all arguments

Comment: +1 as it works with `sh` vs rm fashion

Answer (score 44):

Simple:

`mv` the files you want in a upper directory, `rm` the directory and then `mv` them back.

Comment: Offcourse, mv them to a directory higher. Try not to mv them to a subdirectory you are deleting...

Comment: @Konerak: `rm` without `-r` won't remove subdirectories.

Comment: This will overwrite files with the same name in the destination directory

Comment: I am downvoting this because while it can be handy, it also is non-atomic and effectively removes all files from the directory during a short period of time; this would not be acceptable if, for instance, the files are being shared on the network.

Comment: Also you'd need write access on the parent directory, which you likely not have on a shared web server.

Answer (score 17):

Somewhat similar to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/529861/4724) but no special options are needed, as far as I know the following is "ancient" functionality supported by any (vaguely) /bin/sh resembling shell (e.g. bash, zsh, ksh, etc)

```
rm [^up]
```

Comment: This works for the 1-char filenames. For longer names, sparkie's answer is better.

Comment: What would be wrong with `rm [^up]*`? I do similar things rather often.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - this would delete all files beginning with either u or p, not just those with the names u and p. I think the OP (@Ashot) meant the a-z and u,p,etc. symbolically and not literally.

Comment: @HobbesofCalvin That would delete all files *not* beginning with u or p, not those beginning with them.

Answer (score 15):

Doing it without find:

```
ls | grep -v '(u|p)' | xargs rm
```

(Edit: "u" and "v", as in other places here, are being used as generic versions of entire regexes. Obviously you'll want to be careful to anchor your regexes to avoid matching too many things.)

You're definitely going to want a script if you're going to be doing much of this, as others have suggested.

Comment: grep will not handle extended regexpt by default: either use `-E` or `egrep`

Comment: this will exclude any file containing a `u` or a `p`

Comment: @Matteo No it won't. The grep isn't grepping the files, it's grepping the output of the ls command. You're thinking of something like `grep -L (u|p)' * | xargs rm` where `-L` means list filenames not containing a match.

Comment: @rjmunro Yes it will: `touch u uu; ls | egrep -v '(u|p)'` gives an empty ouput

Comment: Oh, you mean any file who's name contains `u` or `p`, not any file containing a `u` or a `p`. That is correct. You can fix by using `egrep -v '^(u|p)$'`

Comment: Here is remove everything except these matches!
`ls | grep -v 'vuze\|progs' | xargs rm -rf`

Answer (score 7):

In zsh:

```
setopt extended_glob  # probably in your .zshrc
```

then

```
rm ^(u|p)
```

or

```
rm *~(u|p)
```

The second will work even if you have `^` in `$histchars` for history substitution, and of course you can put an arbitrary glob before the `~`.

Answer (score 5):

GLOBIGNORE takes a colon-separated list

```
GLOBIGNORE=u:p
rm *
```

Comment: This does not work on my shell (GNU bash 4.1.5(1)). **Be sure to test it first with something a little less harmful than `rm`** or in a testing directory!

Answer (score 3):

Back in the floppy era I had a dos executable called "Except" that would move things out of the current directory temporarially and execute a command, so you could say:

```
except *.txt del *.*
```

to delete everything but your text files.

This would be a pretty trivial thing to implement as a shell script and if this is the kind of thing you are likely to do more than twice it seems like it would be a good idea.

Comment: It reminded me the same thing. But temporarily moving out of folder may not be a good idea in the era of multitasking :)

Answer (score 3):

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name "u" ! -name "p" -type f -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This will delete all files except u and p in unix

Answer (score 2):

For those preferring to specify arbitrary complex exclude patterns (spanning all affected filenames) in a full blown regexp emacs, posix-awk or posix-extended style (see find man page) I would recommend this one. It excludes `u` and `p` in current dir in this example. This may be handy for scripts.

```
find -regextype posix-awk ! -regex './(u|p)' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Comment: You need to specify a directory before the expression (`find . -regextype ...).

Comment: `-regextype` will only work on GNU versions

Comment: no - my find version (debian squeeze) does  definitively not require an explicit directory before the expression if the current directory should be used

Comment: @sparke: this just works on GNU implementations

Comment: @sparkie: not defining the directory (first parameter) for `find` is a GNU extension of `find` command. The same applies for `-regextype` option. In addition, your command will delete files in subdirectories, too, whereas the original question clearly asked about files in a directory.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another:

```
for FILE in ./*; do if [[ $FILE != ./u* ]] || [[ $FILE != ./p* ]];then rm $FILE; fi; done;
```

It's kind of lengthy and I don't know if you could easily make it into an function that could easily accommodate and arbitrary number of arguments, but it works well.

**And** it's pure bash goodness.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another variant. You can type:

```
rm -i *
```

or:

```
rm --interactive *
```

So `rm` will ask you to confirm deleting of each file.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
find . -type f ! -name 'u' ! -name 'p' ! -name '*.ext' -delete
find . -type d ! -name 'u' ! -name 'p' ! -name '*.ext' -delete
```

in order to delete all files including directories, except u, p and .ext files.

Answer (score 1):

I always use:

```
rm [a-o,q-t,v-z]*
```

This will allow you to define how granular you want to make it. So if you want to delete a through o and Z files you can use:

```
rm [a-o,z]*
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another version using `xargs`:

```
ls -1 | grep -v do_not_delete | xargs -I files rm "files"
```

Note that `xargs -I` is needed to handle filenames including spaces correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way that is hard to mess up:
let's say you want to delete everything except *.pdf:

```
mkdir tmp
mv *.pdf tmp
rm *
mv tmp/* .
rm -r tmp
```

Comment: It would be better to use `rmdir tmp` in that last line instead of `rm -r tmp` -- that way, if previous command failed for any reason or was mistyped, you won't lose all your data.