# Delete all not jpeg files

Tags: linux, bash, find, xargs

I have exercise, in which I have to delete all files, which are not `jpeg`.

I tried `find -type f |xargs file| grep -iv 'jpeg'`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete all files in a directory except some?](http://superuser.com/questions/529854/how-to-delete-all-files-in-a-directory-except-some)

Comment: That question, [How to delete all files in a directory except some?](http://superuser.com/questions/529854/how-to-delete-all-files-in-a-directory-except-some), discusses how to delete files _based on the file's name_.  This question, by contrast, asks how to delete _based on the file's type_ as reported by the `file` command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Deleting based on file mimetype

To delete all non-jpeg regular files in the current directory or its subdirectories, use:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'file -bi "$1" | grep -q image/jpeg || rm "$1"' none {} \;
```

This approach is safe for all file names.  It will work even if the file names have newlines or other difficult characters in them.

#### How it works

- `find . -type f`

  This starts a `find` command, restricting the files found to regular files, `-type f`.
- `-exec bash -c 'file -bi "$1" | grep -q image/jpeg || rm "$1"' none {} \;`

  For all the files found, this runs a bash command to test the file's type.  In particular, `file -bi "$1" | grep -q image/jpeg` will return true if `file` reports that the file has mimetype `image/jpeg`.  The operator `||` assures that the `rm` command which follows is executed only for files which failed the jpeg test.  Thus, all non-jpeg files are deleted.

### Deleting based on file name

To delete all files whose names do *not* end in `.jpeg`:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.jpeg' -delete
```

This approach is also safe for all file names.  It will work even if the file names have newlines or other difficult characters in them.

#### How it works

- `find .`

  Find all files in the current directory and its subdirectories
- `-type f`

  Restrict ourselves only to regular files
- `! -name '*.jpeg'`

  `-name '*.jpeg'` would find all files whose names end in `.jpeg`.  The exclamation mark, `!`, however, means negation.  So, `! -name '*.jpeg'` restricts our search to files whose names do *not* end in `.jpeg`.
- `-delete`

  This tells `find` to delete the files that match the above criteria.

#### Testing

To test the command, leave off the `-delete`:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.jpeg'
```

This will show you what files would be deleted when the `-delete` action is used.

Comment: No, no. There are no files "*.jpeg", they don't have format in name. I can know its name using 'file' command.

Comment: @adrian OK, OK.  See updated answer.

Comment: I didn't find answer. I have to add, that there are a lot of folders in folders, so "ls -l" is not enough.I thought about '-exec', but its accept only one commant and my  favorite "|" doesn't work.

Comment: @adrian Look again: I did not use `ls -l`.  I used `find` which will search all subfolders.  Second, look at __how__ I used `-exec`.  The `-exec` command runs a bash shell and the bash shell fuilly supports features like `|` and `||`.

Comment: Ok, but I have to know what is the type of files ('jpeg'), that why i should use 'file', but that command make it  difficult. After use 'file', i can't use rm to delete files.

Comment: @adrian I added an answer that uses `file` to determine the type.  It is used in the `-exec` clause.  If your browser doesn't show that, please _reload_ the web page.  The argument that I show for the `-exec` clause uses `file` to determine type and then executes `rm` according to the result.  You say it is "difficult" but my answer shows how to do it.

Comment: Thank you, my master. But I have some questions. What "$1" means. I changed it for "{}" and it works. However I want to know what is it. I used it in bash script, but I suspect is something different.

Comment: `$1` means the same thing as in a script: it is the first argument.  Our bash command looks like `bash -c 'commands' none {}`.  The `commands` that are run can reference the value of `{}` as `$1`.   Done this way, it is safe for all file names.  If you change `commands` by replacing `$1` with `{}`, then it will work for simple file names but it will fail if a difficult file name appears.   So, don't do that.

Comment: I  never used "none". What that mean?

Comment: @adrian The `none` is critical for making the code work.  When running `bash -c 'commands' arg0 arg1 ...`, bash interprets `arg0` as the (pretend) name of the program that is being run and assigns it to `$0`.  Next, `arg1`, the file name in our case, is assigned to `$1`.   So, `none` is a placeholder: it is assigned to `$0` which we never use but, without it, `$1` would have the wrong value and the code would fail.

Comment: Where did you learn to it?

Comment: @adrian One can learn a lot about bash/shell by reading the stackexchange sites and also [Greg's FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ).

Comment: Is it possibility to use mkdir with Pipeline?

Comment: @diego9403 Yes, particularly if used with `xargs`.

Comment: Please, look http://superuser.com/questions/961036/copy-files-to-other-folder-find.

Comment: I have to copy files (which are in lot of folders) to folder with its type. For example files lake.jpg (type jpeg) I have to copy to folder 'jpeg', but this folder is in other parent folder, which name is parametr in script. My command: find ./find -type f -exec bash -c ' file -b "$1"|cut -d " " -f 1 |awk -f wa|xargs cp "$1" ' none {} \; Files are copied, but there is an error: cp: ./find/PDF/20163.32630.27874' and find/PDF 20163.32630.27874' are the same file –