# copy files to other folder - find

Tags: find, mkdir

I have to copy files to folder with name with their type using command 'find'. There are a lot of files with a lot of folders. I tried command:

```
find ./find -type f -exec bash -c ' file -b "$1"|cut -d " " -f 1 ' none {} \;
```

But I don't know how I can use mkdir to make folder, when I use "|".

I think about two command. First make the folders from type of files. Second copy files to this folder.

But how I can make this folders.

Comment: This is task from studies and we didn't use rsync.

Comment: I found solution:' find ./find -type f -exec bash -c ' file -b "$1"|cut -d " " -f 1 |awk -f aw' none {} \;|xargs mkdir'
 but I can't copy this file. My command:
'find ./find -type f -exec bash -c ' file -b "$1"|cut -d " " -f 1 |awk -f aw|cp "$1" ' none {} \; '
And error:
cp: omitting directory `find/PNG/'

Comment: I am trying copy files to another folder, but I can't.
Command:

find ./find -type f -exec bash -c ' file -b "$1"|cut -d " " -f 1 |awk -f wa|xargs cp "$1" ' none {} \;

But I only see error:

cp: `./find/PDF/20163.32630.27874' and `find/PDF 20163.32630.27874' are the same file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your file-cut expression to determine the directory name:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'd="../$(file -b "$1"|cut -d " " -f 1)"; mkdir -p "$d"; cp "$1" "$d" ' none {} \;
```

#### How it works

- `d=../$(file -b "$1"|cut -d " " -f 1)`

  This finds the name of the directory corresponding to the file's type.  I added `../` so to put these under the parent directory.  You may want to put them somewhere else.
- `mkdir -p "$d"`

  This creates the directory if it doesn't already exist.
- `cp "$1" "$d"`

  This copies the file to the directory.