# Remove all files but one folder with rm

Tags: terminal, rm

I want to use rm -rf to remove files/folders inside a folder,  but skip or ignore a specific folder.

It has been suggested as duplicated to another quesiton, but that is not the case.
The other quesiton ask about skipping files.  I want to skip a folder with all the content of that folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete all files in a directory except some?](http://superuser.com/questions/529854/how-to-delete-all-files-in-a-directory-except-some)

Comment: not a duplicate.  The other quesitons asks about skipping files.  I need to skip a folder with the content of that folder.

Comment: What did you already try? Did you know that find accepts both `-type f` for files but also `-type d` for directories?

Comment: so I tried the following:   find . ! -name .svn     
The problem is that it returns the files inside the .svn folder anyway.
If I add -type d ,  then nothing is returned

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -name '.svn' -print0 | xargs -0 -r rm -rf
```

does what you want it to do, I believe. It skips the .svn directory and its contents but deletes everything else, files and directories, including those starting with a '.' in the current directory and any subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of a duplicate of link in comments... In any case, for a dir:

```
find . ! \( -type d -and -iname "test" \)
```

To see whether `test` dir is skipped or not.

Then:

```
find . ! \( -type d -and -iname "test" \) -delete
```

Simply `find . ! -iname "test"` for both file and dir.

Comment: Not working for me.    If I have a folder "test" and inside a "file.test",  it still returns the "file.test" in the list.

Comment: Please re-read and retry.

Comment: Ok, back to this. If you want to skip "file.test" you can't use "test". Try `find . ! -iname "*test"`, wildcard `*` means "0 or more chars".

Answer (score 0):

find . -not -path ./.svn/* ! -name .svn

Essentially, the first part excludes all files within that directory, and the second part excludes the directory itself.