# Delete all the folders and file except one folder, from terminal in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, rm

I want to remove all the folders and files but except one. I have a Ubuntu server and I tried several methods and none of them worked.

This is my folder structure.

```
app
app/public
app/public/uploads
app/public/css
app/models
file.txt
```

I want to keep the `app/public/uploads` and delete all other files and folders.

These are the methods I tried:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'public/uploads' ! -name '.*' | xargs rm -rf

find . ! -name 'public/uploads' -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

Answer (score 3):

I actually wanted to achieve a similar behaviour today. I'm wiring documentation for a C# library that I have written with DocFx and the files were generated inside the `_site` folder.

Now, in my particular case, I needed two things, a) to have a git repository inside the `_site` folder, and b) after each build I wanted to remove everything inside the `_site` folder except the `.git` folder and all its contents.

To simulate the behaviour lets see the following structure:

[image]

The goal is to remove all except `.git/**`

So first, what I did was to write a `find .` command and see what I'm getting:

[image]

Then I wrote `find . -mindepth 1 -not -regex "^\./\.git.*"` to exclude the `.git` folder and all its contents:

[image]

Now that I'm happy with the results, all I had to do is to pass the `-delete` flag to my find command, resulting in `find . -mindepth 1 -not -regex "^\./\.git.*" -delete`:

[image]

In case you `find` command does not support `-delete` flag, then you can achieve the same result with `find . -mindepth 1 -not -regex "^\./\.git.*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} rm -rf {}`

```
Be warned, don't use `-delete` or `-print0 | xargs -0 -I {} rm -rf {}` 
if you first don't verify that the output you are getting from `find` command
matches your expectations, otherwise, you will lose data.
```

For my case though, I want to run the command outside of the `_site` folder; thus, my final command looks like so:

`find ./_site -mindepth 1 -not -regex "^\.\/_site\/\.git.*" -delete`

That could also work: `find ./_site -mindepth 1 -not -regex "^.*\/.git.*" -delete`, but it would also preserve any `.git` folder you may have in any subfolder of the folder you want to clean up.

I hope it helps!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the command `rm -r !(app/public/uploads)`. Let me know if this works.

[Source:](https://superuser.com/questions/529854/how-to-delete-all-files-in-a-directory-except-some)

Comment: I tired but it's not working

Comment: This is working for me, try getting into app/public and use the command